# Add user to AD LDS similar to ldifde command

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ldap

Is there a way to add user to AD LDS using c# equvelent to LDIFDE?
In ldifde i use the following to add user:

```
dn: <CN=test-1,OU=Users,DC=LabTest,DC=Jqe,DC=com>
changetype: add
objectClass: userProxy
objectSid: S-1-5-21-1400002233-1419564733-112696330-632522
memberOf: CN=Readers,CN=Roles,DC=LabTest,DC=Jqe,DC=com
```